# Android gridview auto sized imageview and textview

Tags: android, gridview

I want to fix the problem related with fitting auto sized gridview. There is a space between item 1 and item 2 and after item 2. How can I solve it out.

Here are the xml code here

GridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:id="@+id/gridlist">

    </GridView>
```

Wordlist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/city_background"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:padding="15dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/city_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/A"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/city_image"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCH1l.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/city_background"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:padding="15dp"
    >
```

**android:padding="15dp"** remove this padding from above code

**Also :-**

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/city_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight =1
        android:src="@drawable/A"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/city_image"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
```

Comment: I shared the image but the problem is still here.

Comment: Now check the answer

Comment: The problem comes from weight.

Comment: sorry it should be android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 0):

Remove this lines

```
android:padding="15dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
```

It should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/city_background"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/city_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/A"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/city_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/city_image"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you please add your problem screenshot.

Comment: I'd already shared the image after I changed the code.  enter image description here link

Comment: please try to change  android:layout_width="wrap_content" in relativeLayout to  android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: and that     android:layout_width="150dp" in yout ImageView and android:layout_width="wrap_content" in your TextView

Comment: I changed it but nothing changed.

Comment: it does not make sense :( there are no line about width.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I solved it out. THe problem comes from the size of image then, I change some of the code.

Here is the code below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/city_background"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/city_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/city_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/city_image"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```